# How to resolve list of dependencies in Autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I want register type, than resolve type, and then register instance using resolved values. Something like this:

```
//Register type:
builder.RegisterType<ValidateImportMandatoryColumns>().Named<IValidateImport>("MandatoryColumn").As<IValidateImport>();
builder.RegisterType<ValidateImportNonMandatoryColumns>().Named<IValidateImport>("NonMandatoryColumns").As<IValidateImport>(); 

//Resolve
var t1 = Container.ResolveNamed<IValidateImport>("MandatoryColumn");
var t2 = Container.ResolveNamed<IValidateImport>("NonMandatoryColumns");

//Create list with resolved values:
List<IValidateImport> allValidators = new List<IValidateImport>(){t1,t2};

//Register Instance:
builder.RegisterInstance(allValidators).As<List<IValidateImport>>();
```

This is not working. I can't resolve and than register again. Do you know how to do this with Autofac? Maybe is approach wrong, so please tell me if you have better idea. **Goal is to inject list of validators** with different types that use same interface.

Comment: Based on the content of your question, and your stated goal, I've updated the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Autofac* has built in support for collection. If you want to resolve all `IValidateImport`, you can resolve `IEnumerable<IValidateImport>`

```
var allValidators = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IValidateImport>>();
```

See [Implicit Relationship Types](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) for more information for more information.

---

By the way, if you want to update a container, which is not required here, you can use the following piece of code.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder(); 
// do some registration 

var container = builder.Build();


var updater = new ContainerBuilder();
// do other registraitons

// update the container 
updater.Update(container);
```